# Laravel assigning working shift using time column types

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I'm trying to create an employee shift management page. The shift should be assigned by the hours of a day.

Something like this : 
[image]

and below is my table setup :

```
class CreateShiftsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('shifts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('shift_name');
            $table->integer('type');

            $table->time('full_day_start_work_time')->nullable();
            $table->time('full_day_end_work_time')->nullable();

            $table->time('morning_half_start_work_time')->nullable();
            $table->time('morning_half_end_work_time')->nullable();

            $table->time('afternoon_half_start_work_time')->nullable();
            $table->time('afternoon_half_end_work_time')->nullable();
        });
    }
}
```

How can I use the time column type to convert it into the 24-hour format in the controller and display it in the HTML table or am I using a wrong column type to do this? Any help is much-appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is using 24 hour format to save data in column with type of time.
So there is not problem to get it from database.

Then you can format it with `Carbon` to display in correct format:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('09:00:23')->format('H:i')
=> "09:00"                                                                                                                                                                         
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('09:01:22')->format('H:i')                                                                                                                               
=> "09:01"                                                                                                                                                                         
\Carbon\Carbon::parse('17:01:78')->format('H:i')                                                                                                                               
=> "17:01"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, will test it and mark it as the correct answer